# How to select words start with a number in Laravel eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this MYSQL query. I want to select all the words starting with a number. This is the working pure MYSQL query.

```
SELECT 'seriesid', 'seriesname', 'imagepath', 'views', 'scenes'
    FROM `series`
    WHERE `seriesname` regexp '^[0-9]+'
```

Now I want to implement this using Laravel. I made some codes. But not working. Here's my Laravel code for above query.

```
DB::table('series')->
    select('seriesid', 'seriesname', 'imagepath', 'views', 'scenes')->
    where('seriesname', 'regexp', '\'^[0-9]+\'')->
    get();
```

What's the error in ths code ? It always returns an empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your original MySQL query, you aren't looking for quotes in the column data; in your Laravel one, you are. Try removing them.

```
DB::table('series')->
    select('seriesid', 'seriesname', 'imagepath', 'views', 'scenes')->
    where('seriesname', 'regexp', '^[0-9]+')->
    get();
```

Answer (score 2):

To use regex in laravel you have to use whereRaw(). So change this code

`DB::table('series')->select('seriesid', 'seriesname', 'imagepath', 'views', 'scenes')->where('seriesname', 'regexp', '\'^[0-9]+\'')->get();`

TO

`DB::table('series')->select('seriesid', 'seriesname', 'imagepath', 'views', 'scenes')->whereRaw('seriesname regexp ?', array('\'^[0-9]+\''))->get();`

If you are unable to generate the query you need via the fluent interface, feel free to use whereRaw
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

Comment: I did that. But there's an error... Can you check this please.

Comment: Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereRaw() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Comment: @chanu1993 I have edited the answer kindly check now.

Comment: This is not true, [according to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses): "The second argument [to the `where` method] is an operator, *which can be any of the database's supported operators*."

Comment: @miken32 I have given another link where if condition does not work you can use whereraw which is different then where syntax. Plz check it.

Comment: I'm not saying it won't work, but it's not true to say you *have* to use `whereRaw()`. Also, you're linking to 4.2 documentation.

Comment: @miken32 I have changed the link. I just gave an alternate way if regular syntax doesn't work. If you have another way you can submit an answer here.