# Starts with any Digit using Eloquent ORM in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel, using the Eloquent ORM, I have a query which searches for the name of a game in my database starting with the value of `$searchQuery`:

```
return Game::where(Game::gameName, "LIKE", $searchQuery . "%")->get();
```

This is functional, however I cannot get this to work with any digit. I've tried using `$searchQuery = "[0-9]"`, as it would be in a normal SQL statement, but this does not work.

I could not find any solutions searching around or in the documentation, so help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The intent is to search for any single digit at once. So anything starting with 0, 1, ... 9. I want to avoid making 10 different database calls.

Comment: What is the result when you run the query with a numeric value? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the value of `$searchQuery` might be?

Comment: `$searchQuery = "S";`
So all games starting with S are returned.

I can also do numeric single digits like `$searchQuery = "7";`, and this works fine. Id like all single digits at once to be an option.

Comment: Ah. This is a question about SQL, not Eloquent. LIKE does not support range notation. Assuming you are using MySQL, you can find some alternatives in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612580/mysql-like-with-range-doesnt-work

Comment: Ah, I see, I was unaware that LIKE could not be used in this way.

The Regex takes on a slightly different format than the response you provided, I found an exact solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114269/how-to-select-words-start-with-a-number-in-laravel-eloquent-orm